# Backfilling nodes that have ledger gaps

Tags: horizon

One more for you: What are the steps to make horizon db backfill to a specific elder ledger number? A core node may not be fully synced and may have ledger gaps.

Answer (score -1):

In order to ingest a ledger, it must be present in the attached stellar-core, or has been ingested by horizon previously.

Ideally, sync a stellar-core from the desired eldest ledger (using an appropriate `CATCHUP_RECENT` value) and start a horizon instance with a clean db. Horizon will then ingest the longest segment of contiguous ledgers up to present, which should be stellar core's entire history.

Comment: How do you determine an appropriate `CATCHUP_RECENT` value? Isn't `CATCHUP_RECENT` the number of ledger entries to include? How do you convert ledger entries to ledgers?

Comment: @JohnMurphy It's the number of ledgers. Not ledger entries. (Is this in the docs somewhere? using "ledger entries" is indeed semantically confusing in this context)

Comment: Thanks @Tomer Weller. I found it in the example config at https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/docs/stellar-core_example.cfg. That's where my confusion came from. Perhaps the info on it should be made clearer?